# fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github, ubuntu

При попытке клонировании проекта с гитхаба

> $ git clone git@github.com:madputin/site-programmer

выходит ошибка:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal:The remote end hung up
> unexpectedly

С чем это может быть связано и как решить проблему?

Платформа Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нужно сгенерить ssh-ключи с помощью `ssh-keygen` и добавить в свой профиль на github.